# BrowserSync keeps reloading infinitely when using Docker

Tags: docker, django-templates, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

When starting the application (on http://localhost:3001) and editing some files Browsersync keeps reloading and never stops. This however doesn't happen when not using Docker.

Is there a reason for that behavior? Am I missing something? I'm using `"browser-sync": "^2.27.5"` and Gulp version `4.0.2`. Here is the output:

```sh
node_1      | [15:14:32] Finished 'images' after 1.32 min
node_1      | [15:14:32] Finished 'build' after 1.32 min
node_1      | [15:14:40] Using gulpfile /usr/src/app/gulpfile.mjs
node_1      | [15:14:40] Starting 'watch'...
node_1      | [Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8000
node_1      | [Browsersync] Access URLs:
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      |        Local: http://localhost:8000
node_1      |     External: http://172.20.0.4:8000
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      |           UI: http://localhost:3001
node_1      |  UI External: http://localhost:3001
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      | [Browsersync] Watching files...
django_1    | [25/Aug/2021 15:15:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45376
django_1    | [25/Aug/2021 15:15:38] "GET /static/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 200 141793
django_1    | [25/Aug/2021 15:15:38] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5439548
node_1      | [15:15:48] Starting 'html'...
node_1      | ℹ - [HTML] Compiling...
node_1      | ✔ - [HTML] Success!
node_1      | [15:16:09] Finished 'html' after 21 s
node_1      | [15:16:09] Starting 'html'...
node_1      | ℹ - [HTML] Compiling...
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 214 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 72 events)
node_1      | ✔ - [HTML] Success!
node_1      | [15:16:34] Finished 'html' after 25 s
node_1      | [15:16:34] Starting 'html'...
node_1      | ℹ - [HTML] Compiling...
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 4 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 4 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 4 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 4 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 2 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 2 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 4 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 4 events)
node_1      | ✔ - [HTML] Success!
node_1      | [15:17:06] Finished 'html' after 32 s
node_1      | [15:17:06] Starting 'html'...
node_1      | ℹ - [HTML] Compiling...
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 36 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 6 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 51 events)
node_1      | [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 16 events)
```

#### My gulpfile looks like this

```sh
gulp.task('watch', () => {
  browserSync.init({
    // The hostname is the name of your service in docker-compose.yml.
    // The port is what's defined in your Dockerfile.
    hostname: 'django',
    port: 8000,
    proxy: 'localhost:8000',
    open: false,
    reloadDelay: 1000,
    timestamps: true,
    files: ['./dist', './templates/local'],
  });

  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.js}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('scripts'))
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.css}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('styles'))
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.img}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('images'))
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.html}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('html'))
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```sh
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}
  notused:

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: webapp_prodcution_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./app/.envs/.local/.env

  django:
    image: webapp_local_django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/docker/django/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    command: /usr/src/app/docker/django/start_dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/.envs/.local/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  node:
    image: webapp_local_node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/docker/node/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      - notused:/usr/src/app/node_modules/
    command: bash -c "rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules/* && npm run dev"
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same symptoms on a non-Docker project.  I'm using `eleventy` on Windows and have tried fiddling around with the various `browsersync` properties (like `reloadDebounce`, `reloadDelay` etc).  They seem to help, but don't seem to solve the problem where the file changes trickle in over a long period of item.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's a better way but what works for me is the following:

In `gulpfile` I've created a variable of `reload` and set a timeout option of 1 second.

```sh
const reload = done => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    browserSync.reload();
  }, 1000);
  done();
};
```

Next, I passed the `reload` variable, like so:

```sh
// BEFORE
gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.html}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('scripts'))
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);


// AFTER
gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.html}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('scripts'))
    .on('change', reload);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to narrow down the problem on my side after digging into the details a bit more.  I'm using `browsersync` with a static site generator.  When any file changes it regenerates the entire site which results in one to two thousand file changes.  It seems to take `browsersync` a long time to receive all of these events (could be a windows issue), so depending on the `reload*` settings it could result in the near constant browser reloading.

Specifically, setting `reloadThrottle` to anything other than `0` was a bad idea since each `change` event only contained 3-4 files, so having this set to `1000` will reload the browser every second for multiple minutes.  `reloadDelay` seemed to help a bit but was mostly just disguising the issue. Since changes were trickling in every few hundred milliseconds for a long time this still resulted in constant reloads every `reloadDelay` period.

In the end, finding a good middle ground for `reloadDebounce` was what worked for me.  Setting it too high, resulting in needing to wait too long for ALL change events to get received and it was faster to reload manually.  Setting it too low caused it to reload much too quickly.  Setting it just right (between 500-1000 in my case) allowed it to reload reasonably quickly, but bit didn't reload too often.  It's still possible that it'll wait for all file changes before reloading, but it's rare.

So, detailed documentation for all of the configuration properties which will hopefully help others out!

- [`reloadDelay`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-reloadDelay) - after a change occurs, there may be other processing that needs to happen before a page refreshes.  This value adds a delay after browsersync processes any change event before the page reloads.  This should not be confused with `reloadDebounce` since it does not necessarily continually *postpone* the reload until after all changes have occurred, it just delays the initial reload  for the duration of this setting.
- [`reloadDebounce`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-reloadDebounce) - ensures that there have been no new changes for the configured period of time before triggering a browser reload.  If the value is set too high, and the changes occur slowly over a long period of time, this may delay the browser reload for a long time (but will prevent multiple sequential reloads).
- [`reloadThrottle`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-reloadThrottle) - as changes occur, those changes are grouped into "events".  An event may contain one change or multiple changes.  If reload throttle is set to a non-zero value, then browsersync will throttle the processing rate so that only one of these events is processed every `x` milliseconds.  So, if you have change events slowly filtering in (resulting in small batches) then setting this value will cause the events to be processed one at a time with a delay and (potentially) a browser reload each time.